# are @Order/Ordered and @Priority separate concepts?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

Current documentation states:

(AnnotationAwareOrderComparator)

> This implementation retrieves an `@javax.annotation.Priority` value, allowing for additional semantics over the regular `@Order` annotation: typically, selecting one object over another in case of multiple matches but only one object to be returned.

> `java.util.Comparator` implementation that checks Spring's `org.springframework.core.Ordered` interface as well as the `@Order` annotation and the `javax.annotation.Priority` annotation

(Ordered)

> Since Spring 4.1, the standard `javax.annotation.Priority` annotation can be used as a drop-in replacement for this annotation.

- related commits are https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/1ff3af6da37896e229e54fc8592673918f9203f4#diff-0ae6f1c11a501e20ca54f02b5287234555640da5f5b23863bd7b92756a3b4f4fR35 & https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/c6d29f1a314c600c6b2d1cdfc3a21ba66523b037#diff-7647ef528e5ffcfdb8ce8b88d189a906a1e7b46778323bc92cb9783a4991d5abR1225 by @jhoeller & @sbrannen

Implementation seems to agree with that, using those terms in tandem, e.g.:

```
protected Integer getPriority(Object beanInstance) {
    Comparator<Object> comparator = getDependencyComparator();
    if (comparator instanceof OrderComparator orderComparator) {
        return orderComparator.getPriority(beanInstance);
    }
    return null;
}
```

etc.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html#value() clearly uses the term "drop-in replacement", i.e.

> The value is optional and represents an order value as defined in the `Ordered` interface. Lower values have higher priority. The default value is `Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE`, indicating lowest priority (losing to any other specified order value). (...) Since Spring 4.1, the standard `Priority` annotation can be used as a drop-in replacement for this annotation in ordering scenarios.

A "drop-in replacement" by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop-in_replacement) is when a "component [can be replaced] with another one without any other code or configuration changes being required and resulting in no negative impacts.", which implies that the value are also intended to be both functionally and semantically compatible between the two, at least as per this doc.

However, **snicoll** clearly states in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/31544 that they are "separate concepts" because "That's just an internal detail of how this is implemented", and that "[value of] LOWEST_PRECEDENCE is a concept of `@Order` and has nothing to do with JakartaEE's priority."

What is the case here then?

Comment: @M.Deinum Please, don't extrapolate your way of thinking and acting on other people. If you're assuming that other people "think [they] are the only one who are right" and "want to offend people" just because they disagree with you or point out the flaws in your statements, you're failing the litmus test of assumption of goodwill on your side. Also, you're going ad personam here. That aside - I'm not "throwing `@Primary` in the mix", it was always there. Check the source code if you don't believe me and go back to this discussion then, otherwise please just stop spreading misinformation.